# Splitting a large vector into intervals in R

Tags: r

I'm not too good with R. I ran this loop and I have this huge resulting vector of  11,303,044 rows. I have another vector resulting from another loop with dimensions 1681 rows.

I wish to run a `chisq.test` to compare their distributions. but since they are of different length, it's not working.

I tried taking 1681-sized samples from the 11,303,044-sized vector to match the size length of the 2nd vector but I get different `chisq.test` results every time I run it.

I'm thinking splitting the 2 vectors into equal number of intervals.

Let's say

vector1:

```
temp.mat<-matrix((rnorm(11303044))^2, ncol=1) 
head(temp.mat)
dim(temp.mat)
```

vector2:

```
temp.mat<-matrix((rnorm(1681))^2, ncol=1) 
head(temp.mat)
dim(temp.mat)
```

How do I split them in equal intervals to result in same lengths vectors?

Comment: Any test is almost surely going to be highly significant due to the large numbers of cases. It might make more sense to compare with a qqplot (perhaps with a bit of sampling to reduce the plotting load.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chisq.test` is [Pearson's chi-square test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).  It is designed for discrete data, and with two input vectors, it will coerce the inputs you pass in to factors, and it tests for independence, not equality in distribution.  This means, for example, that the order of the data will make a difference.

```
> set.seed(123)
> x<-sample(5,10,T)
> y<-sample(5,10,T)
> chisq.test(x,y)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x and y
X-squared = 18.3333, df = 16, p-value = 0.3047

Warning message:
In chisq.test(x, y) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
> chisq.test(x,y[10:1])

    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  x and y[10:1]
X-squared = 16.5278, df = 16, p-value = 0.4168

Warning message:
In chisq.test(x, y[10:1]) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

So I don't think that `chisq.test` is what you want, because it does not compare distributions.  Maybe try something like `ks.test`, which will work with different length vectors and continuous data.

```
> set.seed(123)
> x<-rnorm(2000)^2
> y<-rnorm(100000)^2
> ks.test(x,y)

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x and y
D = 0.0139, p-value = 0.8425
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks.test(sqrt(x),y)

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  sqrt(x) and y
D = 0.1847, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Comment: I tried kolmogorov's test. however, because my first vector is of size 11,303,044, R printed: Error: cannot allocate vector of size 86.2 Mb.

Comment: How much memory do you have on your machine?  Try calling `gc()` before the KS test.  Or you could simply do a `t.test`.

Comment: Another option is to do the KS test with a random subset of the data.  For example, `ks.test(x,sample(y,10000))`.

Comment: Sorry I might've expressed myself wrong. I have a dataset of related/unrelated individuals. The 2 vectors I obtained(from 2 different loops) are related indiivduals, unrelated individuals. 
So what I'm really looking for is proving that the 2 vectors resulting from their respective loops are different. Because when I generated their respective histograms, They looked completely different. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yup ks.test(x,sample(y,10000)) worked. I even took a sample of 1,000,000 from the large vector. thanks heaps:)

Answer (score 1):

```
mat1<-matrix((rnorm(1130300))^2, ncol=1) # only one-tenth the size of your vector
smat=sample(mat1, 100000)                #and take only one-tenth of that
mat2<-matrix((rnorm(1681))^2, ncol=1)
qqplot(smat,mat2)                       #and repeat the sampling a few times
```

What you see seems interesting from a statistical point of view. At the higher levels of "departure from the mean" the large sample is always  departing from a "good fit" not surprisingly because it has a higher number of really extreme values.

Comment: Thanks for your help DWin this generated an interesting plot.

Comment: Your effort to compare qualitatively with histograms seems reasonable , especially if you constrain 'breaks" to be the same.  The `qqplot` results in a finer grained comparison, and would disclose any "high frequency" differences or weird "tail behavior". But your search for a "significance test" is not recommended on such large samples since it will almost always be "significant" but often meaningless.